# What dielectric materials are used to make film capacitors in hybrid integrated circuit?

Tags: capacitor

What dielectric materials are used to make film capacitors in hybrid integrated circuit?

Unfortunately I can not find a definite answer to my question in the textbooks on electronics materials.
To calculate the film capacitor, I need to choose a suitable dielectric material. This capacitor should be used in a hybrid integrated circuit.
I need to choose a material that is close in value of the dielectric constant to 4.7.

Can I use a polyvinyl chloride with a dielectric constant of 3.1–3.4 for the manufacture of a film capacitor in a hybrid integrated circuit?

If not, what material is best for this?

Comment: You mention "integrated circuit" but that means circuits made on a silicon wafer. For that you need (access to) a foundry (chip factory) and they will determine how the capacitors are made. Only small capacitors (1nF is already quite large) can be made like that and the dielectric will nearly always be silicon dioxide. So I think you're not talking about "integrated circuits". You are asking about **Hybrid** integrated circuits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_integrated_circuit which are "normal" circuits on a (ceramic) substrate.

Comment: I'm not an engineer, so I may be off base.  Still, to my knowledge [hybrid integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_integrated_circuit) use more or less conventional parts on a thick film substrate - your question doesn't arise, because you would just specify a standard capacitor to go on the hybrid board.  If you are referring to a different technology, please define it and maybe provide a link to some background information.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie sorry. A mistake. I wanted to say hybrid integrated circuits.

Comment: @JRE This is a theoretical problem. The question does not specify the specific production technology. Thanks for help. This is an outdated technology. I mainly found material on the production of integrated circuits and, as Bimpelrekkie said,silicon dioxide or tantalum oxide. I think that polyvinyl chloride or polyimide is quite suitable.

Comment: I think **not.** You don't normally "roll your own" capacitors on a hybrid circuit.  You place a standard capacitor, which may be a film capacitor.  If your hybrid technology allows making your own capacitors out of arbitrary materials, then you are dealing with something odd and need to describe it more.

Comment: @JRE, it's certainly possible to roll your own capacitors, and in sufficient volume might reduce costs to do so. You could have a thick film dielectric layer printed with metal above and below. You could have a buried high-Dk layer in the greenboard if it's a multilayer substrate technology. You could do an interdigital capacitor if it's a thin-film design.

Comment: OP, in any of those cases you'd need to find out from your vendor what materials are available, what's their Dk (aka \$\varepsilon_R\$), and what thicknesses can be manufactured. There's no general answer we can give here.